# Converting Smtp Client Mail message to HTML

Tags: c#, email

I have this task where I have to take three columns from a table and their rows and send them to my boss in a very neat and clean professional method.I need help because the method I am using below sends an extremely absurd looking and not aligned form of email. Can you guys help me convert this into HTML and proper format so that it looks neat.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("mydatasourceinfo");
    // Connect to the SQL database using a SQL SELECT query to get all 

    string sqlStr = " select * from thedifference ";
    SqlDataAdapter myCommand = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlStr, myConnection);

    // Create and fill a DataSet.
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    myCommand.Fill(ds);

    DataView source = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    string from = "xxx.com";
    string to = "xxx.com";
    string subject = "data differences";
    string body = "ClientName      |     Salesdiff        |       CallsDiff";

    foreach (DataRow Row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        body = body + " " + "\n" + Row["clientname"] + "  " + "                                       " + Row["salesdiff"] + "                                                                                                  " + Row["callsdiff"] + "\n";
    }

    smtp.Host = "xxx.com";

    smtp.Send(from, to, subject, body);         
}
```

Comment: Did you set [`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to `true`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the IsBodyHtml to true.

```
        var htmlBody = new StringBuilder();
        htmlBody.Append("<table>");
        // TODO: generate the message content
        htmlBody.Append("</table>");

        var msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.From = "";
        msg.Body = htmlBody.ToString();

        var smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Send(msg);
```

To create a nice message, you can use the usual html tags like `table` or `p`(however, html and css have limitations in e-mail, because lots of e-mail clients don't support them properly).

Comment: stmp doesnt give an option as isbodyhtml true. Thats the problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've modified my answer according to that.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to link [Building HTML Emails With SQL Server and XML](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/robert_davis/2010/06/15/Building-HTML-Emails-With-SQL-Server-and-XML/). This should get your work done nicely.